# Three input field searching

Tags: android, search, filter, recyclerview-layout

Is there a easy solution of filter list for three input field at the same time?

The requirement is 3 search fields will showing and active at a same time, then the user can search ANY of the three fields immediately. Each search narrows the results automatically.

Is there have any algorithm or solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me
In your getFilter method

```
if (androidVersion.name()(your 1st field).toLowerCase().contains(charString) 
||   androidVersion.id()(your 2nd field).toLowerCase().contains(charString) 
|| androidVersion.number()(your 3rd field).toLowerCase().contains(charString)
{
filteredList.add(androidVersion);
}
```

Comment: If user search for 1st field and 2nd field or 1st field and 2nd field and 3rd field, then how can it filter list for all user input.. ?

Comment: And it is for list, how can I handle loop for 3 field?

Comment: please check below answer for filter method it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

In your adapter class

```
private ArrayList<MyBean> videoList;//your arrayList
private ArrayList<MyBean> vList;//new list for search view

public Filter getFilter() {

    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            String charString = charSequence.toString();
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                videoList = vList;
            } else {
                ArrayList<MyBean> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (MyBean androidVersion : vList) {
                    //you can add your field here
                    if (androidVersion.name()/*(your 1st field)*/.toLowerCase().contains(charString)
                            ||   androidVersion.id()/*(your 2nd field)*/.toLowerCase().contains(charString)
                            || androidVersion.number()/*(your 3rd field)*/.toLowerCase().contains(charString))
                    {
                        filteredList.add(androidVersion);
                    }
                }
                videoList = filteredList;
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = videoList;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            videoList = (ArrayList<MyBean>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: It didn't work perfectly, but it helped me. Thanks :)